# "I can't understand what does it mean." vs "I can't understand what it means."

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

My English skills are poor. Which of these is correct to say?

> "I can't understand what does it mean"
>    **or**
>   "I can't understand what it
>   means".

Comment: "What does it mean?" is a question. "I can't understand what it means" is a statement (though it implies that you are asking for an explanation).

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks for your interest. Which one is more popular than the other?

Comment: That depends whether you are asking a question or telling someone that you don't understand them!

Answer (score 1):

"I can't understand what it means" is an indirect question. You need to use a direct word order, like in a statement, after what/when/where/if/etc.

"Can you tell me where the bank is?"

"I was wondering how you did that. "

If you really want to use your first example, you need to separate it into two distinct sentences: "I can't understand. What does it mean?"

Answer (score 0):

The second one (*I can't understand what it means*) is correct.

The first one is not correct and would **not** normally be used by a native speaker.  However, a native speaker might say or write something that sounds very similar:

- I can't understand...what does it mean?
- I can't understand--what does it mean?

The phrase *what it means* can be used as part of another sentence, to indicate what the thing is that you don't understand.

The question *What does it mean?* is a complete sentence by itself, and can't be used as part of another sentence (except of course as a quote - *She looked up and asked me, "What does it mean?"*)

Comment: For those who are interested in the more technical answer, even though both *what it means* and *what does it mean* start with the word *what*, it is in a different role. The first one is a dependent clause that can be the direct object of *I can't understand*, using the conjunction *what*. In the second one, *what* is the direct object of the question (*it means what*).